# How To Use onFling Gesture Detector Listener On Recycler View

Tags: java, android

I created a Recycler View adapter and viewHolder class

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       
        public int mPostPositionInDatabase;
     
        GestureDetectorCompat mGestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(mContext,ViewHolder.this);

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTextUserName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            mPostPositionInDatabase = 

            mItemView.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CommentActivity.class);
                            
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }

            );
```

I am trying to perform a onFling event so I can handle the user swiping on each itemView. How can I handle the GestureDetecor onFling() method